# how to hide multiple form and show one of form with event click jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using jquery to hide all  when document ready and when I'm click one of the  btn-primary then  will be show and  hide  in accordance with for each of row.

jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table').DataTable();
$('#formmasuk').hide();
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
$('#formmasuk').show();
$('#buttonmasuk').hide();
   });
});
</script?
```

html

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr style="center">
                    <th>Nik</th>
                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>Jabatan</th>
                    <th>Masuk</th>
                    <th>Keluar</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php  foreach($query as $row):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->nik ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->nama ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->jabatan ?></td>
                    <td>
                      <div id='buttonmasuk'>
                          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void()"
  title="Masuk" onclick="masuk('<?php echo $row->id_kar;?>')">Masuk</a></div>
                      <div id='formmasuk'>
                          <form>
                          <input type="text" name="pass">
                          </form>
                      </div>
                          <td>
                          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  title="Keluar" ></i>
      Keluar</a></td>
                   </tr>
                    <?php 
                    endforeach ;?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

this image when document ready.
why not all  hidden?
[image]
 when I click one of the button masuk (class btn-primary) then  show 
[image]
I want when clik click one of the button masuk (class btn-primary)then  show and  other still hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ids` to `class`.

It should be like the following

```
<div class='buttonmasuk'>
...
<div class='formmasuk'>
```

and the script be like the following

```
$('.formmasuk').hide();
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.formmasuk').show();
  $(this).closest('.buttonmasuk').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html id-s should be unique for the page. Try to add unique id-s to the forms because now you are assingning them the same value "formmasuk"

Answer (score -2):

you need to first add Jquery library to your dom
add this link in your index.html

```
         ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
          crossorigin="anonymous"]
```

and remove the second line of the code datatable
from your script then code is working fine and also please end your script tag properly.